# Finding quaternion $q_x$ in the following equation: $q_x q_1 q_x' = q_2$

Tags: quaternions

Given that $q_1$ and $q_2$ are known quaternions.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find the quaternion that performs a particular spatial rotation. Is that correct?

Comment: The rotation about unit vector $u_x\mathbf{i}+u_y\mathbf{j}+u_z\mathbf{k}$ through an angle $\theta$ corresponds to the quaternion $\mathbf{q}=\cos(\theta/2)+(u_x\mathbf{i}+u_y\mathbf{j}+u_z\mathbf{k})\,\sin(\theta/2)$.

Comment: I'd like to find a quaternion that rotates q1 so it matches q2. The actual problem I was trying to solve is in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087370/finding-the-quaternion-that-rotates-a-coordinate-system-to-match-another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the Quaternion that rotates a coordinate system to match another.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087370/finding-the-quaternion-that-rotates-a-coordinate-system-to-match-another)  You didn't really have to make a new contextless question.